# What's the dimension of this manifold?

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Suppose I have
$$
\begin{align}
     \mathcal{X} &= \mathbb{R}^{N_x} \\
     \mathcal{Y} &= \mathbb{R}^{N_y} \\
     \mathcal{Z} &= \mathbb{R}^{N_z}
\end{align}
$$

And I have a manifold described by $f(x, y) = z^*$ for $z^*\in\mathcal{Z}$ fixed and $x, y\in\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}$ variable. What is its dimension? How can I compute the dimension of a manifold that is given by the function at a point?

Comment: It should be something like $N_{x} + N_{y} - N_z$

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Is your manifold the fiber of $z^*$ via $f:X\times Y \to Z$, or does it consist in all points $(x,y,z)\in X \times Y\times Z$ s.t. $f(x,y)=z$?

Comment: @Desperado I guess it would be something like $\left\{(x, y)\in \mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{Y}\, : \, f(x, y) = z^*\right\}$

Comment: Is it an upper bound because the specific form of $f$ could make it so that the manifold is actually lower dimensional?

Comment: Ok, then $N_x+N_y-N_z$ is an upper bound for the dimension of the manifold. For example, let $f:\mathbb R \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, (x,y)\mapsto x^2+y^2$: $N_x+N_y-N_z=1$ ; if $z^*<0$ the preimage is empty, if $z^*=0$ the preimage is a point and if $z^*>0$ the preimage is a circle.

Comment: If $z^*$ is not a regular value of $f$, this set may well *not* even be a manifold.

Comment: @Desperado Your upper bound would fail if, for example, $f$ were constant with value $z^*$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, well spotted! Do you think we can repair the bound putting $N_z$ equal to the dimension of the Image of $f$?

Comment: @Desperado Using the dimension of the image of $f$ won't do the job. The trouble is that $f$ might be locally constant in some neighborhood, with value $z^*$, but very non-constant elsewhere, so that its image is still big. The best repair, in my opinion, is what Ted Shifrin suggested: Require $z^*$ to be a regular value of $f$. That will (unless I've overlooked something) make the set in question a manifold of the right dimension.

Comment: @AndreasBlass do you mind writing a quick answer talking about why it is an upper bound? I would accept it :)